# RSS feed Laravel Vapor

Tags: xml, laravel, rss, laravel-vapor

I have a simple route that calls a method in a controller to generate an RSS feed of news content.

Works great locally but just will not work in production on Laravel Vapor.

```
public function __invoke()
    {
        return response()
            ->view('rss', [
                'videos' => Video::all()
            ])
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

What's going wrong on Vapor?

Comment: In what specific way does it not work on Vapor? What happens? What error/behavior do you get?

Comment: Endpoint request just timesout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to tweak the method

```php
public function __invoke()
    {
        $xml_version = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
        return response()
            ->view('sitemap', [
                'news' => News::all(),
                'xml_version' => $xml_version
            ])
            ->withHeaders([
                'X-Vapor-Base64-Encode' => 'true'
            ])
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

and then in the view

```php
@php
echo $xml_version;
@endphp
...
```

and we're good.